# Facebook Debugger Document Returned No Data

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

For the longest time I have been messing around with the open graph tags to get facebook to read my site properly but have no luck. Whenever I run my site [www.BrownSpaceman.com](http://www.brownspaceman.com) through facebook's debugger it only grabs the website and sets the name as the website name. It's been incredibly frustrating. I'd be very grateful for any guidance on this. It's incredibly annoying to not be able to share my content easily on Facebook.

Thanks,

Comment: When trying to access you site in my browser, I got the error `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 190840832) (tried to allocate 40896285 bytes) in /home/brownspa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security/modules/free/backup/class-itsec-backup.php on line 148` – try disabling that module, maybe it is preventing Facebook from accessing your site.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but still getting the same thing. :(